Why filenames defined through expl3 strings don't work with \setmainfont?
With the following MCE, we see that filenames can be defined through either (expl3) token lists (..._tl) or strings (..._str) for \input: both work. By contrast, for \fontspec's \setmainfont, only token lists work, as shown if the commented lines are uncommented, the warning message in the terminal being:

luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "Erewhon-Regular.otf" not found.

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{foo.tex}
Foo.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn    \c_my_font_name_tl  {Erewhon-Regular.otf}
\setmainfont{\c_my_font_name_tl}

% \str_const:Nn \c_my_font_name_str {Erewhon-Regular.otf}
% \setmainfont{\c_my_font_name_str}

\tl_const:Nn  \c_my_subfile_tl  {foo}
\input{\c_my_subfile_tl}
\str_const:Nn \c_my_subfile_str {foo}
\input{\c_my_subfile_str}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

Why?
Additional remarks

If only the string is used (not the token list), the font is nevertheless loaded, despite the warning message in the terminal.
If the font is only loaded using luaotfload, there is no warning message in the terminal:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{document}
\str_const:Nn \c_my_font_name_str {Erewhon-Regular.otf}
\font \myfontname = {file:\c_my_font_name_str} at 10pt
\myfontname
Foo.
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


The filecontents and \input parts are completely irrelevant.

They were here just to show that filenames could be defined through strings, e.g. for \input.

Apparently, category codes are important in order to split off the extension. The font is not found at all using XeLaTeX. On the other hand, if you omit .otf from the string and do \setmainfont{\c_my_font_name_str}[Extension=.otf], there is no problem with either engine.

About \input: it's a standard TeX feature that the tokens used for \input are category code agnostic. That's why I say that the comparison with \input is “apples and oranges”.

fontspec removes the extension of the file name by checking whether it is in a clist. The items in this clist have the default TeX catcodes, that is letters have catcode 11 and the full stop has catcode 12. Now, if you use a str variable, all characters have catcode 12. Thus, at the point where fontspec checks whether the extension is in the list, it won't find it, since the catcodes don't match. It then probably searches for the wrong font file. The relevant internal command is \fontspec_sanitise_fontname:Nn.

you would see a similar thing with \includegraphics which would not recognise .png file as .png if it has catcode 12 p n g

I filed a bug report: https://github.com/latex3/fontspec/issues/532

I can't say much about \input (it seems that it does not care about catcodes, so the below explanation does not apply), but as for why you can't use a str variable as font name with fontspec, the reason is that it has catcodes that are different than the expected ones.
If you browse the fontspec-code-user.dtx file (or check the code documentation of fontspec), you will find a command called \fontspec_sanitise_fontname:Nn. This checks whether the extension of the file is in a clist that includes extensions known to fontspec. The items in this clist have the default TeX catcodes, that is letters have catcode 11 and the full stop has catcode 12. For example, .₁₂ o₁₁ t₁₁ f₁₁ is an item in this list.
Now, if you use a str variable, all characters have catcode 12. Thus, at the point where fontspec checks whether the extension is in the list, it won't find it, since the catcodes don't match: In your example, .₁₂ o₁₂ t₁₂ f₁₂ is not an item of the above clist. Therefore, the input is probably interpreted as font name (and not file name) and eventually the font is not found.

If someone has a better idea how to show tokens with catcodes: I am open for suggestions.

try <code>.<sub>12</sub> o<sub>11</sub> t<sub>11</sub> f<sub>11</sub></code>

Likely, this business should be completely done with strings, rather than token lists.

@egreg You mean that the input should be parsed as str by fontspec in the first place? It would make sense. At least, catcodes should not interfere here.

@JasperHabicht Yes, that's my idea.

If \__fontspec_main_DeclareFontExtensions:n were defined as \clist_set:Ne \l__fontspec_extensions_clist { #1 , \tl_to_str:n {#1} }, everything would go through (the extensions are stored with catcodes both 11 and 12). But this is just a hack.
